# Problem with opening screen with onPress in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I dont have any errors but I still cant open screen that I want. Here is my FlatList item:

```
let categories = [ 
        {
            screenName : Player,
            name : "Category 1",
            img : require("../Assets/Slika.jpg"),
        },
```

Here is TouchableOpacity with onPress

```
return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                    data={categories}
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    numColumns={categories.length / 5}
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                    renderItem = {({item, index}) => {
                        return (
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => item.screenName}>
                        <Surface style={styles.surface}>
                            <ImageBackground
                            source={item.img} 
                            style={styles.img}
                            blurRadius={0.5}>
                        <Icon name="music" color="#fff" size={22}/>
                        <Text style={styles.name}>{item.name}</Text>
                            </ImageBackground>
                        </Surface>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        );
                    }}
                />
            </View>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "open screen" ? do you mean navigate to a new screen ?

Comment: it's binding issue. Try onPress={this.navigateToScreen('your_screen')}

Comment: You just pushed a variable to onPress function instead of execute function inside.

Comment: Try `screenName:"Player"` in the object of categories array.

Comment: Yes, I want to open new screen, but there is few items in FlatList and for every item it have to be different screen.

Comment: I tried that already...dont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use navigation:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
...
export default function ClassName() {
const navigation = useNavigation();

function navigateTO(pageName) {
 navigation.navigate(pageName);
}
<TouchableOpacity onPress={navigateTO(item.screenName})>
```

Comment: can you commit?

Comment: See, there's a lot of things related like:
1) Does you have the page created for each new page?

2) Does you route everthing in your home?

Comment: I will commit for 5-10 min and send you link here...

Comment: Here is commit...thank you for help, I am new at react native so that code you write is little bit confusing for me right now...

Comment: I'll take a look

Comment: Can you make it?

Comment: I'll be able to check at 18 Miami time

Comment: Ok bro...thank you a lot. Comment here or send me mail at vuknisavic1@gmail.com if you make it.

Comment: What happened??

Comment: Sorry man, got into a bug issues yesterday and got stuck by late of the night! I'll take a look soon as possible!

Comment: No problem...I understand. Write me here when you make it. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm trying to commit my changes and got denied, please add my user as a contributor andremadureira1993. Also I'd made the correct changes to use navigation, but your project has a lot of issues with mismatch version, you may have to fix than before run it. I'll try to help later again

Comment: Can you download zip and make changes, then commit to your githhub acc?

Comment: I will add you anyway

Comment: Can you commit now?

Comment: What happened bro...can you commit? If you cant tell me to check my github, maybe I made mistake.

Comment: Still gotting denied

Comment: Here is my GitHub screen, think I did everything right?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKNSE.jpg

Comment: Now I got this... I'll push my branch. I'll pin you by gmail

Comment: Thank you man...you saved my project. I will fix mismatch version right now.

Comment: Bro I get hooks error on Expo, when I want to open screen from flatlist item.

Comment: If I understand it is because class component but I am not sure.

Comment: I realise that I have to convert Class to Function

Comment: I made it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thats great to hear!! sorry for the delay, but glad to had helped

Comment: Only thing I had to do in your code is to convert Class to Function.

Comment: Can you check this if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62623602/how-to-play-sound-mp3-in-react-native